# Callback function to a Class member function

Tags: ros, callback, function

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, this question might have just a trivial answer, but because i'm new to ROS and might be looking at the wrong places, I still can't figure it out. So, I want to create a service where the callback function would call a function of an Object (e.g. `Board.executeCommand()` ) . First, is it even possible? If it is, how do you do it? Thank you all..

EDIT: By the way, i'm using C++ as the language.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28132/callback-function-to-a-class-member-function/) by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2012-02-21**:
You should specify which language -- in Python it is as simple as using class_instance.method_name, in C++, you will have to use Boost::Bind.

**Comment by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on 2012-02-21**:
Uh, i forgot to mention that. I'm using C++. I'll edit my question. Could help explaining a little bit how to use Boost::Bind ? cause i'm originally a Java programmer, and still learning C++ as well. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll find your answer here: [UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks)

---

Originally posted by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) with karma: 345 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on 2012-02-22**:
exactly !!! this is the link i've been looking for. Thank you Cav!